# Bus Error when trying to pass int to pointer

Tags: c

I am trying to build a simple assembly emulator.
I am trying to create the set function; the function will take 2 parameters (String arrays) arg1 & arg2.
it will then compare the strings against an array of strings, which is an index for an arraylist of function pointers.

The problem I am having is when I try to set the value of the register.
I have tried many variants of the line:

```
*register_ptr[i] = *(int*)(atoi(arg2));
```

with no success; is there something I am not understanding?

The code will hopefully be more clear:

```
int opcode_set(char* opcode, char *arg1, char *arg2)
    {
      int i, j;
      //printf("%d\n", (int)arg2);
      for(i=0;i<4;i++)
      {
        if(!strcmp(arg1, register_str[i]))
        {
          for(j=0;j<4;j++)
          {
            if(!strcmp(arg2, register_str[i]))
            {
              *register_ptr[i] = *(int*)register_ptr[j];
            }
            else
            {
              *register_ptr[i] = *(int*)(atoi(arg2));

            }
          }
        }
      }
      //printf("%d", *register_ptr[i] );
      INSP++; /* NOP does not do anything except moving the instruction pointer to the next instruction */
      return (0); 
    }
```

EDIT:
declarations for register_str & register_ptr:

```
 const char *register_str[] = {"REGA", "REGB", "REGC", "REGX"};
 int *register_ptr[]={&REGA, &REGB, &REGC, &REGX};
```

I use two arrays in order to decide which opcode, an array of strings, and an array of function pointers, I index through the strings and use the same index location to call the function:

```
int exec_instruction(char *instruction){
int i; //used for indexing 

/* the line below may be useful for debugging to see the current instruction*/
/*printf("executing line: %s", instruction);*/

/* three variables could be used to extract opcode and 
 arguments from the variable instruction */
char *opcode = NULL;
char *arg1 = NULL;
char *arg2 = NULL ;
char *copy = NULL;

/* we need here some functionality to extract opcode, 
 arg1 and arg2 from the string instruction*/
copy = strdup(instruction);
opcode = strtok(copy," \n\r");
arg1 = strtok(NULL," \n\r");
arg2 = strtok(NULL," \n\r");


/* Now we have to call the right function corresponding 
 to the right opcode For example: */
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
  if(!strcmp(opcode_str[i], opcode))
    (*opcode_func[i])(opcode,arg1,arg2);
}

/* for demonstration purpose we execute NOP independent of input
 this line must go in your implementation */
(*opcode_func[0])("NOP",NULL,NULL);

/* return value should be 0 if execution was ok otherwise -1*/
return(0);
}
```

The two arrays I was speaking about:

```
    const char *opcode_str[] = {"NOP", "SET", "AND", "OR", "ADD", "SUB", "SHL", "SHR", "JMP", "PRT"};

    opcode_function opcode_func[] = { &opcode_nop, &opcode_set, &opcode_and, &opcode_or, &opcode_add, &opcode_sub, &opcode_shl, &opcode_shr, &opcode_jmp, &opcode_prt };
```

Comment: What exactly is in arg2? And is that a valid memory address to read a int from?

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean `register_ptr[i] = (int*)(atoi(arg2));`?

Comment: arg2 will be a string, with either a Constant (numbers) or a register(REGA, REGB, REGC, REGX). i dont understand what you mean by your second question

Comment: yer when i do that it says i am making a pointer to integer without a cast

Comment: Your function takes 3 arguments, not 2.  Please show us the declaration of `register_ptr` (and `register_str` while you're at it).  `atoi()` returns an `int`; on many machines, an `int` is smaller than an `int *` and you will run into problems when you convert the one into the other.  Have you printed the values of `arg1` and `arg2` so you know what is being passed to the function?  Or set a debugger breakpoint on the function so you can see what is being passed?  If not, do so. Is the code compiling without warnings even when the compiler is set to 'fussy' (for example, `gcc -Wall -Wextra`)?

Comment: What are you trying to convert arg2 to?  Doing atoi("REGB") is going to return 0. I think you may be misunderstanding what that function does. Or maybe I'm understanding your use case here. Could you post an example of how you would call opcode_set

Comment: Could you also post the specific problem you are having? eg compiler error, segmentation fault, incorrect results?

Comment: i am getting Bus Error core dump when running the program, i am trying to pass the int to the "register" or set the value of one reg to another

Comment: Rename this register_ptr to just what it should be, that is `int register_index[REG_COUNT];`. The whole code is already mashed up, tho it's very short.

Comment: err the code actually works now, its just a case of getting it to exit the loops, an there is significant amount more.

Comment: The new info you posted helps. THe last thing I'd ask for is the instruction string that is causing you problems.

Comment: which i have solved by using return(0);

Comment: it was SET, but now its all good thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the declaration for `register_ptr`, the lines:

```
          *register_ptr[i] = *(int*)register_ptr[j];
        }
        else
        {
          *register_ptr[i] = *(int*)(atoi(arg2));
```

are both wrong (one harmlessly, one less harmlessly).  The first doesn't need the cast; you could perfectly well write:

```
          *register_ptr[i] = *register_ptr[j];
```

The second really doesn't need any casting either, but it doesn't need the level of indirection either:

```
          *register_ptr[i] = atoi(arg2);
```

This assigns the integer returned by `atoi(arg2)` to the memory pointed at by `register_ptr[i]`, which is presumably one of `REGA`, `REGB`, `REGC` or `REGX`.  As written, you are treating the value in `arg2` as an address in your simulator's memory space and reading the value that's there, with all sorts of (probably) unwanted consequences (such as core dumps).

Comment: i still get the core dump when i change the lines, thanks for your help though,

I have tried this before an come to the same problem

Comment: Do you get the same stack trace from the core dump?  If so, it probably wasn't pointing at those lines.

Comment: Hmm i beleive that has worked actually as now i am getting no output which might mean i have done something else wrong

Comment: That, I'm afraid, is quite likely; this change gets you past the first bug, leaving you with a new one to resolve.  I notice that your two arrays `opcode_str` and `opcode_func` would be better as a single array of a structure type.

Comment: This is part of an assignment, i don't know if i could have written this on my own haha. well thank you for your help i am sure its working as the register is taking the values there just not being printed something i have verified